# Cannot cast InputEventArgs to MouseEventArgs

Tags: c#, casting, extension-methods

I'm trying to make this extension method.  Getting an error on the casts saying 'Cannot convert type T to MouseEventArgs'.  Shouldn't I be able to upcast the object (since `MouseEventArgs : InputEventArgs`)?

In case you are curious, I am using this to share event handlers between Mouse and Touch events by just using the base InputEventArgs in the handler method.

```
    public static class InputEventArgsExtensions
    {
        public static Point GetPosition<T>(this T e, IInputElement obj)
            where T : InputEventArgs
        {
            if (e is MouseEventArgs)
                return ((MouseEventArgs)e).GetPosition(obj);
            else if (e is TouchEventArgs)
                return ((TouchEventArgs)e).GetTouchPoint(obj).Position;

            return new Point();
        }
    }
```

Comment: ah good catch on that. unfortunately that poor choice of a name isn't fixing the issue.

Comment: Sorry; yeah I removed the comment after I realized it wasn't causing an issue.

Comment: Check out this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/183923/compiler-fails-converting-a-constrained-generic-type

Comment: So what stops this from going into infinite recursion when it's a `MouseEventArgs`?

Comment: @Servy I'm guessing there is some sort of priority given to non-extension methods? I can tell you it isn't infinitely recursing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried doing this and it worked for me.

```
    public static class InputEventArgsExtensions
    {
        public static Point GetPosition<T>(this T e, IInputElement obj)
            where T : InputEventArgs
        {
            if (e is MouseEventArgs)
                return (e as MouseEventArgs).GetPosition(obj);
            else if (e is TouchEventArgs)
                return (e as TouchEventArgs).GetTouchPoint(obj).Position;

            return new Point();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If e will always derive from InputEventArgs, then just use that type instead of a generic method:

```
public static Point GetPosition(this InputEventArgs e, IInputElement obj)
{
    // Code here   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`MouseEventArgs` already has [GetPosition](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.mouseeventargs.getposition.aspx) method. So I think it's only `TouchEventArgs` which you may want to extend:

```
public static Point GetPosition(this TouchEventArgs e, IInputElement relativeTo)
{
    e.GetTouchPoint(obj).Position;
}
```

Comment: Perhaps, but the point in code where I am using the extension method only has the InputEventArgs type.

Comment: BTW there is also StylusEventArgs which you possibly should consider

Comment: Ugh.  Thanks for the heads up, it will undoubtedly become a bug report sometime in my future if I don't do it now.